# Android multiple labels

Tags: java, android

I'm a new android programmer so pardon me for the basic question, I already found a valid answer but to be more efficient and use a better method I want to ask on the forum.

I want to place about 30 labels on one page. These might contain about 1-2sentences, what is the most efficient way to scroll through these without making them clickable like a button.
Its also better if I can make this in java, right? Because I could use an array to store the different sentences.

Thanks, to all.

Comment: Use ListView in Android.

Answer (score 2):

The ListView does exactly what you want in a memory efficient way.

See more information on it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Comment: Ag, I answered so stupily - and I am JUST busy learning ListViews... lol!

Comment: +1, ListViews are very customisable: you can remove the divider, have custom layouts for each item, define what happens when clicking each row, handle dynamic modifications of your list, etc. Definitely one of the most important widget in the Android ecosystem, very suitable for the mobile format.

Comment: Thanks I believe I have used a similar simple_list